Is there a way to make sure ICD10 code is acceptable for lab tests using CPT or LOINC?
I work with a practice that uses eCW for our EMR.  When providers order certain lab tests, they get kicked back by the testing facility as needing appropriate diagnosis codes due to billing policies from insurance providers.  I am trying to find a way to make sure when our providers order laboratory tests, they do not get kicked back due to the CPT not meeting the "medical necessity policy/ies.  I was wondering if it might be possible to utilize the ICD 10 (medical diagnosis), CPT (procedure codes), and/or LOINC to accomplish this?  A lot of the time, the problem isn't the diagnosis being inappropriate, but that the insurance does not want the ICD 10 code to be specific codes.  For instance, they say not to use diagnosis codes that begin with "W" for any lab tests even if the only applicable diagnosis codes are W codes.
I tried searching stack overflow, eCW users forums, freely available eCW instructions (no access to the help option), eCW-related reddit boards, etc.  Was expecting to find a resource that would allow us to at least search diagnosis codes that would be applicable to the test.  Could not find anything aside from statements that ICD 10 and CPT manuals exist.

When our lab system was modified for use in the USA we had to add a feature that communicated with a 3rd party provider (3M) to perform medical necessity validation. We sent them patient demographics, insurance provider, patient history, ICD9/10 codes, and a list of tests requested. We got back an XML file with details on which tests would be covered by the provider. The rules are complex and ever changing. Outsourcing this task was our best solution.

Do you know what the system uses as a means of validating medical necessity?

3M maintains Medical Necessity Dictionaries for each region. You can download regular updates to these dictionaries and do the cross referencing yourself or have 3M do it for you.

Here is a public record of Monterey County in California paying $30k a year for Medical Necessity Dictionary files.  See items 10 and 11 in 3M Amendment #2.  https://monterey.legistar.com/LegislationDetail.aspx?From=RSS&ID=1140453&GUID=3EE513A9-431F-444D-8EF4-8ED8BDB0A3C9&FullText=1

3M charges for these dictionaries I would assume?  or is it that Monterey county pays 30k a year for 3M to do the cross referencing?

It looks like the 30k is just for the disctionaries. They also pay another 150k for the software and training to perform the cross referencing via a coding and reimbursement system. I am not sure if they interface with and existing EMR system or replaced it with all 3M stuff.

Another example: NY State Comptroller paid 3M COMPANY c/o SUNY - Upstate Medical University C600666 $727,548.99 11/18/2010 to 11/17/2014 SOFTWARE LICENSE & SUPPORT FEE FOR CODEFINDER AND MEDICAL NECESSITY DICTIONARY Equipment - IT Hardware/ Software
